# dependent is set to destroy, nullifies instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

There's a model with two dependent models, set to destroy.

```
class Deal < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :detections, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I call destroy_all on it.

```
Deal.where("updated_at < ?", 2.days.ago).destroy_all
```

And get a violated constraint error.

```
(0.7ms)  BEGIN
(2.0ms)  UPDATE "likes" SET "deal_id" = $1 WHERE "likes"."deal_id" = $2  [["deal_id", nil], ["deal_id", 94063]]
(0.7ms)  ROLLBACK

ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "deal_id" violates not-null constraint)
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (8, 4, null, 2020-03-14 03:04:25.824787, 2020-03-14 03:04:25.824787).
```

Looks like Rails is trying to `nullify` the dependent likes even though I specified `destroy`. And I have not a faintest idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation was re-defined in a concern.

```
module Likeable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :likes

    ...
  end
end
```